# Looking for a function that preserves concavity

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the function
$$
f(x,y) = g(x) y
$$
where $g$ is some other function. We can restrict ourselves to $y\geq 0$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$. I would like to find a function $g$ with the following properties:

1. $f$ is concave
2. $g(x)\geq 0 $ for $x\in [0,1]$
3. $g$ looks like a rough inverted U, i.e. there exists an $0<x^*<1$ such that $g$ is increasing before $x^*$ and decreasing after it.

Does such a function $g$ exist? If so it would be great to have an example. Many thanks!

Comment: $f$ can't be concave in $y$ since $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f=0$. Do you mean $f$ is concave in $x$: $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f<0$? If so, then I beleive an up and right shifted, down facing parabola would work (something like f(x)= -(x-.5)^2+1).

Comment: It doesn't have to be strictly concave. Weak concavity is enough.

Comment: That parabola does not work. $f$ is not concave in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hessian of $f$ is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}g''(x)y & g'(x) \\ g'(x) & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues need to be nonpositive. Since the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, you need
$g''(x)y \leq 0$ and $-(g'(x))^2 \geq 0$.
The last condition implies that $g$ is constant.